# Serializing / de-serializng DecisionTree

Tags: accord.net

I'm using decision trees from Accord.MachineLearning v3.8.0.

Viewing the tree after training in DecisionTreeView works OK.  However if I serialise the tree using

```
Accord.IO.Serializer.Save(tree, fileName);
```

and then deserialise it with

```
DecisionTree tree = Accord.IO.Serializer.Load<DecisionTree>(fileName);
```

and then try to visualise it in DecisionTreeView

```
decisionTreeView.TreeSource = tree;
```

I will get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Accord.MachineLearning.DecisionTrees.DecisionNode.toString(Codification >codebook)
>     at Accord.MachineLearning.DecisionTrees.DecisionNode.ToString()
>     at Accord.Controls.DecisionTreeView.convert(DecisionNode node)
>     at Accord.Controls.DecisionTreeView.convert(DecisionNode node)
>     at Accord.Controls.DecisionTreeView.update()
>     at Accord.Controls.DecisionTreeView.set_TreeSource(DecisionTree value)

Comment: You could try deserialising and reserialising a tree in the same process, and compare the objects in the debugger to see what's changed, but unless there's something obvious that might not help.

Answer (score 2):

Found the fix. For some reason, the DecisionNode:s lose the Owner property value in serialising/de-serializing the DecisionTree. Simply after de-seralization, iterate over the DecisionNode:s of the DecisionTree and set the Owner of each DecisionNode to be the DecisionTree itself.